# Farseer physics engine: The name 'ConvertUnits' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xna, c#, physics

http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/farseer-physics-in-xna-4-0-for-windows-phone-1/

I tried this Farseer tutorial but I always get that error message in the following lines:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle2.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle2.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(rectangleSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(rectangle3.Position),
                                        null,
                                        Color.White, rectangle3.Rotation, new Vector2(rectangleSprite.Width / 2.0f, rectangleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                        SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

What is wrong? I added the two usings to my code but I always get this error message:
The name 'ConvertUnits' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I added the class ConvertUnits.cs to my project, but I still get the error message. What is wrong?

Comment: Missing project namespace, possibly.

Comment: Thanx. I forgot to change the namespace.